# How to store an image into database

Tags: c#, .net

How can I use openfiledialog and a picturebox and upload an image and store it into SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep field datatype as varbinary(Max) in the database table. then convert image into byte array. then pass this byte array as parameter respect to your varbinary field. it will be saved in your database. while retrieving, get value from database as byte array the convert it into Image object. hope this sequence helps you. or more code example you can find [here](http://www.shabdar.org/store-save-images-in-sql-server.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you g0ogled `c# store image in sql`, the first 2 results would have been

[Store or save images in SQL Server database using C#](http://www.shabdar.org/store-save-images-in-sql-server.html)

[Store or Save images in SQL Server](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Store_images_in_SQL_Serve.aspx)

Comment: Although astander . . . isn't the point of SO also to be a repository of all good questions and answers, not just a last resort if we can't find it with google?

Comment: I will aggree with that statement, if the OP had used google, which I clearly believe wasnt the case **X-)**. Even so, hope this helps, and that the OP can learn from these links, or maybe others that exist

Comment: @Richard - of course, however, this question has been asked many times over on SO: http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+store+image+in+sql+site:stackoverflow.com